# Image Slider in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to make Image Slider with two images per slide by using HTML and CSS alone.

What I have trying:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg" style="width:640px; height:280px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 1</h3>
              <p>Image 1 Image 1</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="./resources/images/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2" style="width:640px; height:280px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 2</h3>
              <p>Image 2 Image 2</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="./resources/images/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3" style="width:640px; height:280px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 3</h3>
              <p>Image 3 Image 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="item active">
            <img src="./resources/images/image4.jpg" alt="Image 4" style="width:640px; height:280px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 4</h3>
              <p>Image 4 Image 4</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="./resources/images/image5.jpg" alt="Image 5" style="width:640px; height:280px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 5</h3>
              <p>Image 5 Image 5</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
            <img src="./resources/images/image6.jpg" alt="Image 6" style="width:640px; height:280px;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 6</h3>
              <p>Image 6 Image 6</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The above code Shows only 1 image per slide(1st Column) and Empty space in 2nd Column.

**Expected Output:**

I need two columns with two images. When I hit Next Control, next two images will appear. When I hit Previous Control, previous two images will appear. (All this done by HTML and CSS alone not JS or others.)

I hope you all understand!

Comment: Where is your Slider JS code?

Comment: I don't use any JS code here. Only HTML alone. @KrupalPanchal

Comment: I think this will help you https://www.bootply.com/89193.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div> 
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 1</h3>
              <p>Image 1 Image 1</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
<div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div> 
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 2</h3>
              <p>Image 2 Image 2</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div> 
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 3</h3>
              <p>Image 3 Image 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="item active">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div> 
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 4</h3>
              <p>Image 4 Image 4</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div> 
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 5</h3>
              <p>Image 5 Image 5</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item">
           <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
<img src="./resources/images/image1.jpg"  >
          </div> 
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h3>Image 6</h3>
              <p>Image 6 Image 6</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

you can do this